# SR197: Non unique primary key on DB.DBA.SYS_XML_PERSISTENT_NS_DECL

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, virtuoso

I am trying to upload `ttl` files to Virtuoso. There are around 180 files being uploaded to a single graph in a parallel fashion (parallel stream in java), and sometimes I get this exception and the uploading fails after few files have been uploaded. This happens sometimes, and other times the uploading finished successfully with no error or exception. Below is the exception with the stack trace that I encounter.

```
    SR197: Non unique primary key on DB.DBA.SYS_XML_PERSISTENT_NS_DECL. 
org.apache.jena.shared.JenaException: org.apache.jena.shared.JenaException: virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoException: SR197: Non unique primary key on DB.DBA.SYS_XML_PERSISTENT_NS_DECL.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:562)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:591)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:689)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:765)
    at com.elsevier.reaxys.loader.TripleStoreLoaderApp.getFilesAndUpload(TripleStoreLoaderApp.java:65)
    at com.elsevier.reaxys.loader.TripleStoreLoaderApp.run(TripleStoreLoaderApp.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.elsevier.reaxys.loader.TripleStoreLoaderApp.main(TripleStoreLoaderApp.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```

Can someone guide me what this error means and how can I avoid it?
Thank You in advance!!

Comment: Exact and complete versions of Java, JDBC Driver, Jena Provider, Jena itself, and Virtuoso server binary are all relevant details which may matter. If all of these are not the very latest available as of this writing, start by updating all of them. (Recent fixes and enhancements are relevant to your activity.) If the issue persists, it may be better raised [as an issue on the Virtuoso Open Source project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/).

Comment: hello @TallTed the versions being used are mentioned below,                                    
java - 17(temurin) , virtjdbc4 - 3.122 , virt_jena_v4_4 - 1.42 , apache-jena-libs - 4.5.0 , virtuoso-opensource - 7.2

Comment: This is not an issue with Apache Jena.

Comment: Please note that `virtuoso-opensource - 7.2` covers [more than 7 years, and multiple sub-versions](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/releases/), up to and including the [latest, 7.2.8](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/releases/latest), which also delivers the latest JDBC Driver and Jena Provider. If not 100% certain that all are the latest, please update, and retest. If this issue persists, please log on our [Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com/) or the [GitHub Project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/)

Comment: hey @TallTed i have updated the maven dependencies of the libraries mentioned above by you and i havent encountered that error from last 2 tests, i will be doing multiple tests so that i am sure it wont come again, if it comes i will post this on the community. Thank you for the help.